# What is the flow of Plotly dash program (python)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Actually I am new with python dash library and learning Plotly dash. Where I am bit confused that how this program flows when we run it?

(Like in java program first main method runs and then functions one by one in main method gets run...)

Can anyone just explain or will share the flow diagram?

Comment: Check out the documentation. It is pretty comprehensive. https://dash.plotly.com/layout

Comment: Thanks. Just need know whether callbacks gets run first or layout part?

Comment: And in callbacks which callback will get run first?

Comment: in your question you really compare to a top-down based paradigm in java.  dash specifically (as is HTML and javascript) an event based paradigm .  Switch your conceptual view before then focusing on technical aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plotly Dash workflow -

a) First create an app.

```
   app = dash.Dash(__name__, requests_pathname_prefix = '/app', 
                   external_stylesheets = external_stylesheet)
```

b) Secondly create the app layout.

```
   app.layout = html.Div([
                      html.Div([....])
                     ])
```

c) Thirdly create the callbacks

```
   @app.callback(Output(component_id = 'id' , component_property = 'data'), 
   [Input(component_id = 'id',  component_property = 'value'])
```

d) Fourthly, run the app.

```
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```